# id мастера, в классе заказов. Django

Tags: python, django

В моём проекте осуществляется запись к парикмахеру. Запись включает в себя имя, эл. почту дату, но я ещё хочу id мастера добавить, но не знаю как.
Вот класс записей

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата и время',default=timezone.now)
```

Так же у меня есть класс для мастеров, там имя, тип и т. д. Сам клас по-умолчанию содержит и id мастера, так вот как мне добавить id мастера в класс подписок?

UPD:
Я хочу, что бы у меня в админке было 4 поля

```
class SubscriberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ["name", "email", "date", "master_id"]
  search_fields = ('name','email', "date", "master_id")

class Meta:
    model = Subscriber
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте для этого поле типа `models.ForeignKey` с указанием нужного класса – айдишник подтянется сам:

```py
class Master(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)

class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    date = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата и время', default=timezone.now)
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master,
        related_name='subscribers', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
```

Как можно заметить, там есть дополнительные полезные аргументы. Подробнее и с примерами [смотрите в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

Comment: Спасибо, но я, честно говоря, не совсем понял, как из этого я смогу получить id мастера. Вот, например, я хочу получить, что бы в админке в заказе фигурировали имя, эл. почта, дата и id мастера, я указал все эти поля и у меня всё заполняется, кроме id, что логично. Подскажите, я может быть сказал, что-то не так.

Comment: У объекта `s` типа Subscriber можно обратиться к полю `s.master`, что даст объект типа Master, а у него, как и у любого объекта Django ORM, можно получить id обращаясь к полю `pk`. Получается всё просто: `s.master.pk`

Comment: я понимаю, про что вы говорите, и нечто похожее я даже сделал (когда добавлял разных мастеров), но я всё же не до конца понял, как я это использовать  в моём случае. Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: @KnMO Чтобы в админке вбивать именно айдишник? Зачем, ведь по умолчанию там будет выпадающее меню с выбором объекта?

Comment: Да, я могу из админки создавать запись, но цель получать заказы через сам сайт от пользователя, что я уже сделал. Конечно, лучше было бы если бы туда сразу имя сохранялось, но я пока не знаю, как это сделать, потому что я считываю id мастера.

Comment: @KnMO Можно реализовать на своём фронте такой же выпадающий список для выбора пользователем нужного мастера, чтобы пользователь видел и тыла имена, а под капотом были айдишники. Для этого можно использовать Django Forms или кастомный код на HTML/JS и Питоне.

Comment: @ AivanF Хорошо, попробую с этим разобраться. А то, что я хотел изначально, я так понял не правильно и так не делают?